# How does Krishna clarify the ambiguity Arjuna perceived in Bhagavad Gita chapter 3 verses 1-2?

Tags: krishna, bhagavad-gita

https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/3/verse/1-2

> अर्जुन उवाच |
> ज्यायसी चेत्कर्मणस्ते मता बुद्धिर्जनार्दन |
> तत्किं कर्मणि घोरे मां नियोजयसि केशव || 1||
> व्यामिश्रेणेव वाक्येन बुद्धिं मोहयसीव मे |
> तदेकं वद निश्चित्य येन श्रेयोऽहमाप्नुयाम् || 2||

> BG 3.1-2: Arjun said: O Janardan, if You consider knowledge superior to action, then why do You ask me to wage this terrible war? **My intellect is bewildered by Your ambiguous advice.** Please tell me decisively the one path by which I may attain the highest good.

Answer (score 1):

*Here, the knowledge connotes , knowledge concerning the Self*

To draw an analogy,

> Tirumandhiram (2290) , a treatise by a well-known Rishi(of yore)Tirumoolar , explains  the state of Knowledge and that of ignorance.

> **Marathai Maraithathu Mamatha
> Yanai
> Marathil Marainthathu Mamatha Yanai
> Parathai Maraithathu Parmuthal Bhootham
> Parathil Marainthathu Parmuthal Bhootham
>
> 2290
>
> Mara - Wood, Para- Brahman, Bhootha-Pancha bhootha,Yanai-Elephant.**
> An enraged wooden elephant, scares a child so long as, its not perceived to be all wood, akin to a Jnanis realization that it's all Brahman , not so long as its all seen as Panchabhoothas

It is evident that the state of knowledge is truly superior to the state of the delusion of the child ( upon seeing the enraged elephant) needless to say.

(Nevertheless, when in state of delusion (ignorance) , Knowledge is ambiguous.)

The competence of the child when in knowledge and when in delusion are mutually exclusive , and it is not  possible to enjoin a unique path(yog(a)), for such varying competencies. (Here competence can be understood as plane of awareness).

Then why at all, anything  concerning Knowledge should be spoken of to the child in delusion causing ambiguity , as it lacks competency.

This is because any solution (here yog(a)),  that is stated to dispel the delusion , is for the sake of progressing towards the highest good ( here Knowledge of the Self). So Sri Krishna gives a big picture Sankya(connoting Knowledge) , in chapter 2 before detailing  Karma yoga in chapter 3.

Why any action (here yog(a))? Because there is never a time(not even a split second) , a Jiva can remain without indulging in any karma(which includes Manasika karma as well) , as stated in
BG 3.5

> **na hi kaśhchit..** There is no one who can remain without action even for a moment. Indeed, all beings are compelled to act by their qualities born of material nature (the three guṇas).

Usually the subsequent shloka  clarifies, the question raised as part of the previous shloka (as it is structured as samvadha - dialogue)

> **śhrī bhagavān uvācha
> loke ’smin dvi-vidhā niṣhṭhā purā proktā mayānagha
> jñāna-yogena sāṅkhyānāṁ karma-yogena yoginām**
> The Lord said: O sinless one, the two paths leading to enlightenment were previously explained by Me: the path of knowledge, for those inclined toward contemplation, and the path of work for those inclined toward action.(*BG 3.3 - Translation by Swami Mukundananda*)

> Thus in accordance with
> the difference in the states consisting of purification and non-
> purification  of the mind, two kinds of steadfastness have been
> taught to the very same person, (viz.) you, in, 'this knowledge
> about the Self has been imparted to you. However, listen to this
> (wisdom) which is to be adopted in the Yoga (of Karma)' (2.39)
> So the idea is that, since both are useful to the very same person
> in accordance with the difference in his states, therefore there is
> no futility in imparting the instruction (to the very same person) in spite of the difference in eligibility.(*Portion of Swami Madhusadhana Saraswati s commentary*)

Hence the choice of the path, as stated in the commentary, depends on One's  competence/state ,though details concerning both the choices are imparted. In this way the ambiguity is resolved by Sri Krishna